# converting string to address in web3js

Tags: solidity, remix

So, I've this contract that I'm running in remix. I pass the input value as `"padur"` and I see in console that the return value is `{"0": "address: 0x000000000000000000000000000000000003fdfb"}`. This basically means that the 'string' input that I gave got converted into 'address' type by my contract.

Question is - when I interact with this contract using web3js, I'm passing the value as string but it doesn't get converted (instead got an error - web3.js:14789 Uncaught Error: new BigNumber() not a number: kelambakkam). How do I go about this?

How does remix browser converts it while web3js is not able to convert? It's just base20 address isn't?

Contract:

```
contract Test {
    //address mg;
    function getString(address _mg) returns (address) {
         return _mg;
    }
}
```

Edit:

When I run this html page, I get an error that "web3.js:14789 Uncaught Error: new BigNumber() not a number: Padur". What's the fix?

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/main.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bignumber.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/web3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        providerURL = "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545";
        var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_mg","type":"address"}],"name":"getString","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];
        contractAddress = "0x6f2014378e4d34382cf93d906762ff2d12cdb769";
        var Web3 = require('web3');
        var web3 = new Web3();
        web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerURL)); 

        function callMethod() 
        {
            var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
            var myContractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddress);

            var accountToSubmitNOC = web3.eth.accounts[0];
            var unlockAccount = web3.personal.unlockAccount(accountToSubmitNOC,'',300);
            var msg = document.getElementById('idString').value; //IS THIS CORRECT?     
            var txHash = myContractInstance.getString(msg, function (err, res) {if (!err) { console.log(err, res); document.getElementById("idReturnValue").innerText = JSON.stringify(res); }});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border = 0>
        <tr>
            <td>String</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="idString" value="Padur"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" onClick="callMethod();" id="btnSetString">Write</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Return Value =  <div id="idReturnValue"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit #2 -

With Bytes32 instead of address

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract Test {
    //address mg;
    function getString(bytes32 _mg) returns (bytes32) {
         return _mg;
    }
}
```

--

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/main.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bignumber.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/web3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        providerURL = "HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545";
        var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_mg","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"getString","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];
        contractAddress = "0xce503c6b2111f4e76d8a43689bbbea794887d014"; //deployed in local ganache
        var Web3 = require('web3');
        var web3 = new Web3();
        web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerURL)); 

        function callMethod() 
        {
            var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
            var myContractInstance = MyContract.at(contractAddress);

            var accountToSubmitNOC = web3.eth.accounts[0];
            var unlockAccount = web3.personal.unlockAccount(accountToSubmitNOC,'',300);
            var msg = document.getElementById('idString').value;
            var txHash = myContractInstance.getString(msg, function (err, res) {if (!err) { console.log(err, res); document.getElementById("idReturnValue").innerText = JSON.stringify(res); }});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border = 0>
        <tr>
            <td>String</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="idString" value="Padur"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" onClick="callMethod();" id="btnSetString">Write</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Return Value =  <div id="idReturnValue"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of conversion Remix is doing. If you want to store a string, use `string` or maybe `bytes32`. What do you _want_ to have happen when you supply a string like "padur"? What address do you expect that to turn into?

Comment: string like "padur" gets converted to "0x000000000000000000000000000000000003fdfb" by remix. I want the same to happen in web3js.

Comment: Why is that the conversion? (What's the relationship between "padur" and "0x3fdfb"? Is there some algorithm that converts from one to the other?)

Comment: Edited the question with html.. kind of my 2nd question.             var msg = document.getElementById('idString').value; //IS THIS CORRECT?

Comment: That line of code is fine. You haven't explained what you're trying to do. There's no obvious answer to the question "What address does the string 'padur' represent?" See my answer for what Remix is doing. It's just a bug, and `web3.js` is correctly throwing an exception instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that Remix doesn't raise an error for this invalid input is just a bug in the `bn.js` library. It [was fixed](https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/commit/e924509e561f7ada230117b63cbe827c980c2d70) in the master branch of `bn.js` to throw an exception, but there hasn't been a release since that fix.

If you really want to replicate this nonsense, install `bn.js@4.11.8` (the current version) and do `new BN('padur')`. But you're just getting garbage from trying to parse the ASCII as a base-10 number despite the characters being outside the range 0-9, and future versions of the library will fix this bug by throwing an exception instead.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for pointing out the 'nonsense'. I was looking out for this exact reason that you mentioned, so, thank you. And about bytes32, I changed the 'address' type to 'bytes32' and tried with same html and got 'web3.js:3914 Uncaught Error: invalid address' error. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Could you share your updated code (contract and JavaScript) that use `bytes32`?

Comment: Yes sir.. Edited the original question with it.

Comment: Is there a full stack trace? Do you know which line of your code is triggering that error message?

Comment: Ah, my bad.. didn't specify '{from:accountToSubmitNOC},' in line24.. I'm so sorry! shouldve checked!